# Rendering Efficiency in Android - OpenGL ES 10

Tags: android, opengl-es

Currently writing code to create both a background and a 3D object in OpenGL() 10. I've run into a problem though with the rendering of the object after I have changed the identity matrix. For whatever reason, the code is hugely inefficient, and the object won't move smoothly at all, it jumps in bits and pieces.

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // Clear the screen to black
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
   background.loadTexture(gl, mContext, R.drawable.room);
    // Position model so we can see it
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -20.0f);
    gl.glScalef(7.5f, 7.5f, 0);

    //gl.glTranslatef(tempX, tempY, 0);

    //Set rotation
    gl.glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 0); //glRotatef(angle, x, y, z) rotates each axis by a certain angle
    background.draw(gl);

    // Position model so we can see it
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glTranslatef(tempX, tempY, -10f);

    gl.glScalef(counter*1f,counter*1f,counter*1f);
    System.out.println("Z value is now 1f*"+counter+" and tempX is "+tempX+" and tempY is "+tempY +"*****************************");
    gl.glPushMatrix();

    //gl.glTranslatef(tempX, tempY, 0);

    //Set rotation
    gl.glRotatef(-60, 1, 1, 0); //glRotatef(angle, x, y, z) rotates each axis by a certain angle

    cube.loadTexture(gl, mContext, R.drawable.wood);
    // Draw the model
    cube.draw(gl);
}
```

The cube class is shown below:

```
class MyCube {
    private final IntBuffer vertexBuffer;          //Buffers store vertex data for improved performance
    private final IntBuffer textureBuffer;         //Buffers store texture data for improved performance
    static int one = 65536;                            //Length of a side
    int half = one / 2;

//Cube data
public MyCube() {

    int vertices[] = {                          //Sets coordinates of the vertices.
            // FRONT
            -half, -half, half, half, -half, half, //Sets x, y and z coordinates for each of the four vertices of the front face
            -half, half, half, half, half, half,
            // BACK
            -half, -half, -half, -half, half, -half,
            half, -half, -half, half, half, -half,
            // LEFT
            -half, -half, half, -half, half, half,
            -half, -half, -half, -half, half, -half,
            // RIGHT
            half, -half, -half, half, half, -half,
            half, -half, half, half, half, half,
            // TOP
            -half, half, half, half, half, half,
            -half, half, -half, half, half, -half,
            // BOTTOM
            -half, -half, half, -half, -half, -half,
            half, -half, half, half, -half, -half,};

    int texCoords[] = {                             //Sets values of texture coordinates. (Only u and v. Not x, y, and z.)
            // FRONT
            0, one, one, one, 0, 0, one, 0,
            // BACK
            one, one, one, 0, 0, one, 0, 0,
            // LEFT
            one, one, one, 0, 0, one, 0, 0,
            // RIGHT
            one, one, one, 0, 0, one, 0, 0,
            // TOP
            one, 0, 0, 0, one, one, 0, one,
            // BOTTOM
            0, 0, 0, one, one, 0, one, one,};

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = vbb.asIntBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = tbb.asIntBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texCoords);
    textureBuffer.position(0);
}

//Draws cube
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FIXED, 0, vertexBuffer);         //glVertexPointer(size (number coords per vertex), type (data type of coords, stride (byte offset between consecutive vertices), pointer (pointer to first coord in the array)

    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // workaround bug 3623
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FIXED, 0, textureBuffer);


    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);                  //Render primitives from array data. (mode (specifies kind of primitives, first (specifies starting index of arrays), count (number of indices to be rendered))
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 4, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 8, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 12, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 16, 4);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 20, 4);
}


static void loadTexture(GL10 gl, Context context, int resource) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), resource);
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);
    gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    bmp.recycle();
}
```

}

Any pointers regarding the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're calling cube.loadTexture() every frame. This is probably very slow and doing it only once during initialization should be enough.

Also, I'm not sure you're loading the texture properly. Usually, you generate a texture ID (with glGenTextures) and bind it (with glBindTexture) before loading the texture. You might want to look into that problem too.

Comment: Yeah, that sounds like it would be a pretty huge issue. Cheers!